# Principle: layers flipped when importing from sketch

Tags: layers, sketch-app, import, principle-app

I have the problem, that certain layers in principle are flipped after I imported from sketch.

In Sketch:

[image: Sketch design]

Outcome in Principle

[image: Principle Outcome]

What do I have to do in Sketch to prevent this from happening? I used "transform > flip horizontal" in sketch to flip those layers in the first place, so there might be a correlation here ... maybe someone has experienced this himself and has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I also posted this question in the principle [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/752853024840625/permalink/1149530048506252) group and there the following workaround was suggested:

> Just tried to recreate the problem, pretty annoying, anyhow here's how
> to fix it. When you flip the speech bubble group, just ungroup it and
> notice that the flip option is no longer hi lighted. And then import.
>
> [image]
>
> Gabriel Dorin

Thanks for your help, Gabriel!

On Principle's official [Twitter](https://twitter.com/principleapp/status/844652045919567873) it was stated that this problem will be examined more closely and hopefully eventually fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to draw a "same" pic as beautiful as yours, But I failed :)

[image]
Actually, You can copy the "Mama" pop shape first. 
(be careful, don't group pop shape and text, that's the key.)

[image]
Second flip it. (without a text group)

[image]
Third, type your text.

[image]
Finished! View in Principleapp.